# c# time format weirdness

Tags: c#

I have the following string TheTimeFormat as the custom time format:

```
  "{0:h:mm tt}"
```

I have the following DateTime TheTime:

```
  {1/14/2011 2:19:00 AM}
```

I have the following statement

```
  ThisTime = TheTime.ToString(TheTimeFormat);
```

Why is ThisTime equal to "`{0:2:19 AM}`" . It should be 2:19 AM and I'm not seeing why. Not that in a gridview, I use the following statement and it works like a charm:

`((BoundField)(MyGrid.Columns[0])).DataFormatString = TheUserPreferences.UserTimeFormat`; where TheUserPreferences.UserTimeFormat is the same format string.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put a time format into `DateTime`'s `ToString` method, you don't need the placeholder; that is, you could have this:

`TheTimeFormat = "h:mm tt";`

and

`ThisTime = TheTime.ToString(TheTimeFormat)`

would give you the desired output.

**EDIT:**

Per the extended question in the comment, this would allow you to put your format in something that requires a placeholder (and store the aforementioned version of TheTimeFormat in the db):

string formatWithPlaceholder = "{0:" + TheTimeFormat + "}";

I just briefly played around with `string.Format` instead of concatentation, but having the braces in the format is giving issues. Nonetheless, this works, but I don't particularly like the concatenation.

Comment: ah ok; what about in my gridview then? In the database, I'm storing the string "{0:h:mm tt}" as the user's time format; what do I need to do with the statement ((BoundField)(MyGrid.Columns[0])).DataFormatString = TheUserPreferences.UserTimeFormat if I change the database to "h:mm tt" ?

Answer (score 0):

Change `TheTimeFormat` to simply **`"0:h:mm tt"`**.

You only need the *"{X:YYY}"* format when you are using `String.Format()` or the other methods like `Console.WriteLine()` that use `String.Format()` internally.